# Find m so that the equation $e^{\vert{x}\vert}=m(x+1)$ has two distinct solutions

Tags: real-analysis

$m$ is a real parameter. I need to find $m$ so that the equation
$$e^{\vert{x}\vert}=m(x+1)$$ 
has two distinct real solutions.

I thought about applying Rolle's theorem.
I wrote $f(x)$ as $$\frac{e^x}{x+1} -m$$ when $$ x \in  [0, \infty)$$ and as $$\frac{e^{-x}}{x+1} -m$$ when $$x \in (-\infty, -1) \cup (-1,0)$$

I've found the derivative of $f(x)$ and I know I should be now making a table using Rolle's theorem, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

You can take, for instance, $m=2$. Then:

- In $(-\infty,0]$, $f(x)=e^{\lvert x\rvert}$ is decreasing and $g(x)=2(x+1)$ is increasing. Besides, $g(-1)=0<f(-1)=e$ and $g(0)=2>f(0)=1$. So, the equation $f(x)=g(x)$ has exactly one solution in that interval.
- In $[0,\infty)$, you have (again) $g(0)=2>f(0)=1$ and furthermore $g(2)=6<e^2=f(2)$. So there is another solution there.

Actually, there is only ne solution in $[0,\infty)$, but what matters is that what I did proves that your equation has two solutions when $m=2$.

More generaly$$\{x\in\mathbb R\mid\text{the equation has at least $2$ solutions}\}=(1,\infty).$$

Comment: You are right. Thanks.  I think I might have been unclear in my post, sorry for that. I need to find all the Ms for which the equation has two distinct real solutions, not only one M. So I need to find the interval of M.

Comment: Can you at least decide whether you are going to use the symbol $m$ or the symbol $M$?

Comment: I use m, but I thought "ms" looked weird, so I used M in my comment because "Ms" looked better. Because I'm not familiar with stackexchange, I didn't know how to make $m$. I hope you can understand that.

Comment: I see. In that context, I type $m$'s.

Comment: Also, doesn't the equation also have two distinct solutions  when $m \in (-\infty, -e^2)? $

Comment: Sure! Sorry about that. I don't know why, but I thought that you were interested only in positive $m$'s.

Answer (score 0):

The slope, say $m$, at $x=0$ of the tangent to $y=e^x$ is equal to $1$.It follows that if $m\gt1$, because of the convexity of $y=e^x$, the line $y=m(x+1)$ cuts $y=e^x$ in two points and consequently also in two points to the curve $y=e^{|x|}$.

It is not difficult discard the values of $m\le1$.

Thus all value of $a\gt1$ can be chosen.